# Set Key and Value inside Loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, foreach

I'm trying to add all the data inside a loop using foreach from a MySQL query. The data includes the key and the value. But in my code, it's enclosed with an integer key before the array that I want.

Here's the code:

```
$count_get_airlines = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_shipping_airlines" );

foreach ($get_airlines as $airlines_data) {
  $data[] = [$airlines_data->letter_code => $airlines_data->shipping_airline];
}
print_r($data);
```

The result below:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [CA] => Air China ) 
    [1] => Array ( [PX] => Air Niugini ) 
    [2] => Array ( [OZ] => Asiana Airlines ) 
    [3] => Array ( [CI] => China Airlines ) 
    [4] => Array ( [MU] => China Eastern Airlines ) 
    [5] => Array ( [CZ] => China Southern Airlines ) 
    [6] => Array ( [ET] => Ethiopian Airlines ) 
    [7] => Array ( [EY] => Etihad ) 
    [8] => Array ( [BR] => Eva Air ) 
    [9] => Array ( [GF] => Gulf Air ) 
    [10] => Array ( [JL] => Japan Airlines ) 
    [11] => Array ( [7C] => Jeju Air ) 
    [12] => Array ( [KE] => Korean Airlines ) 
    [13] => Array ( [KU] => Kuwait Airlines ) 
    [14] => Array ( [MU] => Malaysian Airlines ) 
    [15] => Array ( [WY] => Oman Air ) 
    [16] => Array ( [QF] => Qantas Airlines ) 
    [17] => Array ( [QR] => Qatar Airways ) 
    [18] => Array ( [BI] => Royal Brunei ) 
    [19] => Array ( [SV] => Saudia Airlines ) 
    [20] => Array ( [TG] => Thai Airways ) 
    [21] => Array ( [TR] => Tiger Airways ) 
    [22] => Array ( [TK] => Turkish Airlines ) 
    [23] => Array ( [UA] => United Airlines ) 
    [24] => Array ( [MF] => Xiamen Airlines ) 
    [25] => Array ( [PR] => Philippine Airlines ) 
    [26] => Array ( [DL] => Delta Air Lines ) 
    [27] => Array ( [CX] => Cathay Pacific Airways ) 
    [28] => Array ( [SQ] => Singapore Airlines ) 
    [29] => Array ( [NH] => All Nippon Airways ) 
    [30] => Array ( [EA] => Emirates Airlines ) 
    [31] => Array ( [AK] => AirAsia Phils. ) 
    [32] => Array ( [5J] => Cebu Pacific ) 
);
```

What I want:

```
Array(      
    'CA'=> 'Air China (CA)',
    'PX'=> 'Air Niugini (PX)',
    'OZ'=> 'Asiana Airlines (OZ)',
    'CI'=> 'China Airlines (CI)',
    'MU'=> 'China Eastern Airlines (MU)',
    'CZ'=> 'China Southern Airlines (CZ)',
    'ET'=> 'Ethiopian Airlines (ET)',
    'EY'=> 'Etihad (EY)',
    'BR'=> 'Eva Air (BR)',
    'GF'=> 'Gulf Air (GF)',
    'JL'=> 'Japan Airlines (JL)',
    '7C'=> 'Jeju Air (7C)',
    'KE'=> 'Korean Airlines (KE)',
    'KU'=> 'Kuwait Airlines (KU)',
    'MU'=> 'Malaysian Airlines (MU)',
    'WY'=> 'Oman Air (WY)',
    'QF'=> 'Qantas Airlines (QF)',
    'QR'=> 'Qatar Airways (QR)',
    'BI'=> 'Royal Brunei (BI)',
    'SV'=> 'Saudia Airlines (SV)',
    'TG'=> 'Thai Airways (TG)',
    'TR'=> 'Tiger Airways (TR)',
    'TK'=> 'Turkish Airlines (TK)',
    'UA'=> 'United Airlines (UA)',
    'MF'=> 'Xiamen Airlines (MF)',
    'PR' => 'Philippine Airlines (PR)',
    'AK' => 'AirAsia Phils. (AK)',
    'NH' => 'All Nippon Airways (NH)',
    'CX' => 'Cathay Pacific Airways (CX)',
    '5J' => 'Cebu Pacific (5J)',
    'DL' => 'Delta Air Lines (DL)',
    'EA' => 'Emirates Airlines (EA)',
    'SQ' => 'Singapore Airlines (SQ)' 
);
```

What am I missing? What am I doing wrong?
Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks!
-Eli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the key, rather than creating a new array inside of the array.

```
$count_get_airlines = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_shipping_airlines" );

$data =[];
foreach ($get_airlines as $airlines_data) {
  $data[$airlines_data->letter_code] = $airlines_data->shipping_airline;
}
print_r($data);
```

Comment: All your answers are right! I just thought and tried it, too. Thank you guys! 9minutes more before I can accept your answers. :)

Answer (score 1):

Please try with this :

```
$count_get_airlines = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_shipping_airlines" );

foreach ($get_airlines as $airlines_data) {
  $data[$airlines_data->letter_code] =$airlines_data->shipping_airline;
}
print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making an array of array, this is not what you want. You want to create an associative array. Try with this code :

```
$count_get_airlines = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_shipping_airlines" );

foreach ($get_airlines as $airlines_data) {
     $data[$airlines_data->letter_code] = sprintf('%s (%s)',
          $airlines_data->shipping_airline,
          $airlines_data->letter_code
     );
}
print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$count_get_airlines = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_shipping_airlines" );

foreach ($get_airlines as $airlines_data) {
  $data[$airlines_data->letter_code] = $airlines_data->shipping_airline;
}
print_r($data);
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.